# PeopleSoft Query Union to Existing Query

Tags: sql, report, union, peoplesoft

In PS Query, is it possible to create a union with an existing query? Basically I need to take a query, union it with a duplicate (with a minor change). Unfortunately, they query is quite complex, with tons of expressions.

I have full access to the database, so I'm not limited to the query tool (for building - this is something that a basic user will run from query viewer)

Answer (score 1):

As a direct answer to your question, no, that isn't possible in ps qry.

What I would do is, since you have full access to the database, create the query you want to connect to as a view, and then use a union w/ that view instead of the query, ie.

```
(the query you're working on)
union
select * from name_of_new_vw
```